# iOS Core Data, not fetching a entity that has just had its relationship updated

Tags: ios, core-data

Problem:
When i fetch an entity that had its relationship updated in the same context, the fetch-request returns a nil.

Explanation:

The Data Mode: **Contact <---> Expense (One to many relationship)** with "serverId" property of a Contact to be unique and because of some additional rules i cannot use "Constraints" in Core Data and instead use the following code.

Now when inserting a array of expenses from a web response and i have multiple expense's for the same contact. The following code returns a nil, even when the contact is present in the same context, if it has an update.

```
if let entity = Contact.fetch(serverId: serverId, context: context) {
    return entity
} else {
    return Contact.new(serverId: serverId, context: context)
}
```

---

Below is the debugger log for support:

- Server id is the id that we are using as input for predicate.

```
(lldb) po serverId
55001
```

- Coredata fetch returns a nil

```
(lldb) po Contact.fetch(serverId: serverId, context: context)
nil
```

- the context already knows about the object, as its just been updated. You can see the updated key is a relationship.

```
(lldb) po context.updatedObjects.filter { ($0 as? Entity)?.serverId == serverId }.count
1

(lldb) po context.updatedObjects.filter { ($0 as? Entity)?.serverId == serverId }.first?.changedValues().keys
▿ Optional<Keys>
  ▿ some : Dictionary.Keys(["expenses"])
    ▿ _variant : _Variant
      ▿ object : _BridgeStorage<__RawDictionaryStorage>
        - rawValue : (Opaque Value)
```

- the entity gets fetched after resetting the context.

```
(lldb) po context.reset()
0 elements

(lldb) po Contact.fetch(serverId: serverId, context: context)
▿ Optional<Contact>
  - some : <Contact: 0x6000015371b0> (entity: Contact; id: 0xe7984dad6d91badc <x-coredata://593D407B-BF00-4923-980E-FDC7BEBD46C1/Contact/p834>; data: <fault>)
```

---

Additional Details added:

Entity is just a protocol wrapper, a simplified code is below.

```
protocol Entity {
  var serverId: Int64 { get set }
}

extension Contact: Entity {}
```

The fetch implementation, to reuse using multiple 'Entity' types.

```
extension Entity {

 static func fetch(serverId: Int64, context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> Entity? {
     let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "serverId == '\(String(serverId))'")
    return context.fetch(Entity.self, predicate: predicate)?.first
 }

func fetch<T: NSManagedObject>(_ type: T.Type, predicate: NSPredicate?, sort: [NSSortDescriptor]? = nil) -> [T]? {

  let context = self
  let request = T.fetchRequest()
  if let predicate = predicate {
      request.predicate = predicate
  }
  if let sortDescriptors = sort {
      request.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors
  }
  
  var results: [NSFetchRequestResult] = []
  
  do {
          results = try context.fetch(request)
      } catch {
          print("Error with request: \(error)")
      }
  
  return results as? [T] ?? []
}
```

---

Temp Fix: Added by checking for the object in the current context

```
if entity == nil, context.hasChanges == true {
           
   entity = context.updatedObjects.first { ($0 as? Entity)?.serverId == serverId } as? Entity

   if entity == nil {
       entity = context.insertedObjects.first { ($0 as? Entity)?.serverId == serverId } as? Entity
   }
}
```

Comment: Please show the implementation of `fetch(serverId: context:)`. What is `Entity`?

Comment: @jrturton added the requested details.

Comment: You can change the format string of your predicate to use `%@` and pass the `serverId` as a parameter. You don't need to convert it to a string and use string interpolation. In general, though, querying Core Data by "id" is a bit of a smell. It is an object persistence system and you typically just need to hold references to the particular object and use relationships in your entities.

Comment: If it was me I'd have the debugger pause in your `fetch` method, to look at `results` and see what's there. My guess is that `results` is not empty but that your return line is failing on the `as?`, leading to a nil result.

Comment: Also your simplified definition of `Entity` makes it hard to follow the code, because `Entity.self` would not compile in your `context.fetch(...)` since it doesn't match the generic requirement of `T: NSManagedObject`. Maybe you can't include everything but the question seems to be missing some crucial detail.

Comment: And, your `context.fetch` line is calling a function on `NSManagedObjectContext` that you did not include. If you mean the function that you did post, please edit the code so that it shows which functions belong to what classes/protocols.

Answer (score 1):

```
(lldb) po context.updatedObjects.filter { ($0 as? Entity)?.serverId == serverId }.count
1

(lldb) po context.updatedObjects.filter { ($0 as? Entity)?.serverId == serverId }.first?.changedValues().keys
▿ Optional<Keys>
  ▿ some :(["expenses"])
    ▿ _variant : _Variant
      ▿ object : _BridgeStorage<__RawDictionaryStorage>
        - rawValue : (Opaque Value)
```